# How to Intialise on double pointer char array like below?

Tags: c++, c

I'm searching to initialize data of char type like below. but I'm not sure on how to do this

```
char* data[ ][ ] = { 
          {"", "index1", "clock1", "Rate1"}, 
          {"", "index2", "clock2", "Rate2"},
          {"", "index3", "clock3", "Rate3"},
          {"", "index4", "clock4", "Rate4"}
}
```

so that when I want to assign data of above table to other variables like below

```
for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
  char k[][];
  for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++ )
   {
      k[i][j] = data[i][j];
   }

}
```

and my expected output is like this

```
k[i][1] = "index1", k[i][2] = "clock1", k[i][3] = "Rate1"
k[i+1][1] = "index2", k[i+1][2] = "clock2", k[i+1][3] = "Rate2" etc.,
```

How could I initialize the variable data like above to get the values like mentioned in output?

Comment: c or c++? They are different languages and the answers will be different

Comment: Beyound telling us if it's `C` or `C++`, you should also tell us how are you getting those iterations limits (`6` in this case). `6` will access out of bounds elements in `data` array, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: `k[i][j] = data[i][j];` makes little sense.  Left side is a `char`.  Right side is a `char *`.  Please explain what this line is meant to do.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to note in the `k` assignment loop.  You are looping 0-6 when the array bounds defined in data are 0-3 (4 elements).  You initialized `k` within your for loop.  `k` will need bounds because it is not being initialized.  Remember, arrays in C are of a fixed size.  Here is the code I'm referring to:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
  char k[][]; /* Re-initialize here? */
  for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++ )
   {
      k[i][j] = data[i][j];
   }
}
```

`k` will need to be initialized with bounds like this:

```
char* k[4][4];
```

Also, your assignment of data is not doing what you think it is.  You want to initialize it like this:

```
char* data[4][4] = {
          {{""}, {"index1"}, {"clock1"}, {"Rate1"}},
          {{""}, {"index2"}, {"clock2"}, {"Rate2"}},
          {{""}, {"index3"}, {"clock3"}, {"Rate3"}},
          {{""}, {"index4"}, {"clock4"}, {"Rate4"}}
};
```

In reality though, this also is not going to be very helpful because, as I said above, arrays are of fixed size.  Elements `data[0][x]` are all single element arrays of char.  They will serve no purpose.  I think you want to assign different strings to them.  Assigning/accessing `data[0][x][y]` where `y` is greater than 0 will be undefined behavior.  It looks like what you really need here is variable length strings.  Since you tagged this question with C++, an easy C++ solution would be to use `std::string` here.  If you really need totally variable length strings in C, you will need to use dynamic memory allocation.  For a more simple approach, it would be better to assign `data` with a fixed string size.  Later, if you want to assign different strings, you will want to use `strcpy`.

Below is a solution for you.  I used 20 as the fixed string size.  You may want more space.

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char data[4][4][20] = {
          {{""}, {"index1"}, {"clock1"}, {"Rate1"}},
          {{""}, {"index2"}, {"clock2"}, {"Rate2"}},
          {{""}, {"index3"}, {"clock3"}, {"Rate3"}},
          {{""}, {"index4"}, {"clock4"}, {"Rate4"}}
    };

    int i;
    int j;
    char* k[4][4];
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
            k[i][j] = data[i][j];

    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        for(j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            printf("%s\n", k[i][j]);
}
```